# MVC5 dropdownlistfor get values to list in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a model for customers where inside i have a list of another class for customer type and number. In my view I am passing back the values to controller using model.

```
public class Arama
    {
      public List<MusteriTip> musteriler = new List<MusteriTip>();
}
public class MusteriTip
{
     public string musteriTip{get; set;}
     public int    musteriSayi{get; set;}
}
```

My view is ( the number(sayi) will be choosen from dropdown and the type(tip) is the id of the dropdown):

```
<li>
  <span class="ttl"><asp:literal runat="server" />Yetiskin</span>
   <div class="smll2-select">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MusteriTip, new SelectList(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 1), new { tabindex = "1", id = "passadt" })
   </div></li>
```

In my view user will use a dropdownlistfor to select the number of customers. I want to be able to get the values from dropdownlistfor and enter the values into my model. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you include the code from your view?

Comment: I have included the view

Comment: btw, `<asp:literal runat="server" />` is going to be ignored by your razor view.  It will be passed straight through to the browser, which will make your html invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `DropDownListFor` by itself to post the set of available values.

You can however, combine it with `HiddenFor`.

Based on the portion of your view that is posted, I am assuming that the model for the view is `Arama`, and that `Arama` actually looks like this:

```
public class Arama
{
    public List<MusteriTip> musteriler { get; set; }

    public MusteriTip MusteriTip { get; set; }
}
```

Then your view can do this:

```
@model Arama

<div class="smll2-select">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MusteriTip.musteriSayi, new SelectList(Model.musteriler, "musteriSayi", "musteriTip"), new { tabindex = "1", id = "passadt" })
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.musteriler.Count; ++i)
     {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.musteriler[i].musteriTip)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.musteriler[i].musteriSayi)
     }
</div>
```

This assumes that you initially populate the `musteriler` list in your model.

However, be very cautious relying on lists of available values bound to the model, because of the potential for security vulnerabilities (e.g. overposting, see [Think Before You Bind](http://www.codethinked.com/aspnet-mvc-think-before-you-bind)).  E.g. someone can easily post a value that is not in the list.

Note:
With this approach `Arama.MusteriTip.musteriSayi` will be bound when the form is posted, but `Arama.MusteriTip.musteriTip` will be `null`.  So your controller will need to base its processing on `Arama.MusteriTip.musteriSayi`.  If you want `Arama.MusteriTip` to be fully bound, you will need to look at implementing a custom modelbinder.